# Prove that for two continuous curves that "touch" in a single point, the two tangents in that point are equal

Tags: derivatives, optimization, proof-verification, curves

Prove that if two continuous, first order differentiable curves reach a common value in a single point without intersecting, the tangent line of the two curves in that point must be the same.

My argument is posted as an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1468374): does it constitute an acceptable solution?

[image]

Comment: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$ are two continuous, differentiable curves, intersecting in a single point. Something is missing here.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: The pair $f(x)=x, g(x)=2x$ seems a simpler example, but I suspect there's something more in the question....

Comment: Surely there's something more; it's a pity the author decided not to put it in words.

Comment: @thank you, I updated the description of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, where $f(x) > g(x) \forall x \neq t $ and $f(x) = g(x)$ in $x = t$.

Then we can show that $f'(t)$ must be equal to $g'(t)$ because, if not, e.g. if $f'(t)>g'(t)$, then we could find two point $t+i$ and $t-i$ where $f(t+i)>g(t+i)$ and $f(t-i) < g(t-i)$, this last one contradicting our hypotesis, and similarly if $f'(t)<g'(t)$ we could find a point $t+i$ where $f(t+i)<g(t+i)$ contradicting again our hypotesis.
Then, as $f(t)$ is equal to $g(t)$ and $f'(t)=g'(t)$ the tangent line is the same.

The same reasoning can be applied if $f(x) < g(x) \forall x \neq t $ just inverting the name of the functions.

Comment: Would a reasoning like that be considered acceptable in a non-math research paper ?